# Search Kit search for cases and roles

Tags: civicase, roles, searchkit

On search kit I am trying to create a table with case related information in it (e.g. case status, case type, country). To achieve this I have created a 'search for cases' with the relevant filters and fields. However, I would additionally like to add a column for a specific case role. Is there a way to add case roles (other than the case client) to a case search on search kit?

Answer (score 1):

I remember there being a Case Contacts entity but it seems to have gone missing. But the reverse is available - start with Contacts and then you can join on Contact Case Roles, or start with Related Contacts.

EDIT: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3843

Comment: Thank you, that way around seems to work. Next step is to remove duplicates of cases (where multiple people have the same role). Ill play around with it!